# Boto 3 DynamoDB batchWriteItem Invalid attribute value type when specifying types

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a strange problem with Python Boto3 when trying to do a batch_write_item to a DynamoDB table. I am following the [documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_write_item) and trying to write a singe item. The table is setup correctly and I can run batch-write-item via the AWS cli no problem.

Assuming the client and DynamoDB are set up correctly I run:

```
client.batch_write_item(RequestItems={
    "myTable": [
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "name": {
                        "S": "hello"
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "S": "world"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

I get the following error:

**botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: Invalid attribute value type**

If I change it, removing the types and run:

```
client.batch_write_item(RequestItems={
    "myTable": [
        {
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": {
                    "name": "hello",
                    "value": "world"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

It works as expected.

I need to use the previous format which follows the documentation and is compatibale with AWS cli.

Is the documentation wrong or I missed a configuration setting, version issue or something else?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This just got me as well, looks like you're using a DynamoDB *resource*, not a *client*. They both provide the same function but it acts very slightly differently. Here's what you're looking for:

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.ServiceResource.batch_write_item

That aside, the docs are still pretty unclear. Here's what I found:

- When using a **resource** (what you're currently doing), you **may** specify the type of non-key attributes, and you **must not** specify the type of key attributes
- When using a **client** (the other option), you **must** specify the type of all attributes.

Using the DynamoDB resource:

```
resource = boto3.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url='http://localhost:8000')

mytable = resource.create_table(
    TableName='mytable',
    KeySchema=[{ 'AttributeName': 'name', 'KeyType': 'HASH' }],
    AttributeDefinitions=[{ 'AttributeName': 'name', 'AttributeType': 'S' }],
    ProvisionedThroughput={ 'ReadCapacityUnits': 5, 'WriteCapacityUnits': 5 }
)

try:
    resource.batch_write_item(RequestItems={
        'mytable': [{ 'PutRequest': { 'Item': {
            'name': { 'S': 'myname' },
            'value': { 'S': 'myvalue' }
        }}}]
    })
    print(f'resource, specify all types : write succeeded.')
except Exception as e:
    print(f'resource, specify all types : write failed: {e}')

try:
    resource.batch_write_item(RequestItems={
        'mytable': [{ 'PutRequest': { 'Item': {
            'name': 'myname',
            'value': { 'S': 'myvalue' }
        }}}]
    })
    print(f'resource, specify value only: write succeeded.')
except Exception as e:
    print(f'resource, specify value only: write failed: {e}')

try:
    resource.batch_write_item(RequestItems={
        'mytable': [{ 'PutRequest': { 'Item': {
            'name': 'myname',
            'value': 'myvalue'
        }}}]
    })
    print(f'resource, specify none      : write succeeded.')
except Exception as e:
    print(f'resource, specify none      : write failed: {e}')
```

Output

```
resource, specify all types : write failed:
    An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the BatchWriteItem operation: Invalid attribute value type
resource, specify value only: write succeeded.
resource, specify none      : write succeeded.
```

And then using the DynamoDB client (replace all "resource"s above with client)

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb', endpoint_url='http://localhost:8000')
try:
    client.batch_write_item(RequestItems={    
....
```

Output

```
client, specify all types : write succeeded.
client, specify value only: write failed: Parameter validation failed:
    Invalid type for parameter RequestItems.mytable[0].PutRequest.Item.name, value: myname, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
client, specify none      : write failed: Parameter validation failed:
    Invalid type for parameter RequestItems.mytable[0].PutRequest.Item.name, value: myname, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
    Invalid type for parameter RequestItems.mytable[0].PutRequest.Item.value, value: myvalue, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: You are right, was using the resource instead of the client.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message, but it ended up being a different issue. In my case, I was sending a `BatchWriteItem` request, but had a request that looked like this:

```
"PutRequest": {
    "Item": {
        "Id": "5cc230c65d0948c0bcb5910cc9312e6a",
        "Platform": "slack",
        "SlackMessageId": None,
        "SlackUserId": "U016H83F39V",
        "SlackTeamId": "UTKUSRRSL&0",
        "SlackOrgId": "TTKUSRQM6",
        "Timestamp": Decimal("1618593370.910027027130126953125"),
        "Selection": "yellow",
        "Elaboration": "",
        "Emotion": None,
        "MeetingHours": None,
        "PrivateElaboration": None,
        "Reactions": None,
    }
}
```

The issue is that according to the [API documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html#:%7E:text=the%20sort%20key.-,PutRequest%20%2D%20Perform%20a%20PutItem%20operation%20on%20the%20specified%20item.%20The%20item%20to%20be%20put%20is%20identified%20by%20an%20Item%20subelement%3A,-Item%20%2D%20A%20map):

> Attribute values must not be null; string and binary type attributes must have lengths greater than zero; and set type attributes must not be empty. Requests that contain empty values are rejected with a ValidationException exception.

The issue is the `None` values, replacing them with non empty strings (i.e. `'null'`) solves the issue and lets the request go through! Hope this helps someone out.

Comment: You could just omit those attributes instead of storing them with a value. DynamoDB is semi-structured so you can have different attributes and a different number of attributes for each item.

Comment: That's a good point, was just considering that this morning as well. Thanks for the note!