# batch_write_item using dynamodb.client() to write large csv to dynamodb table in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to insert a large csv file (5M records) to dynamodb using dynamodb_client.batch_write_item().
When I insert using dynamodb_client.put_item(), it works fine but I need to be able to use it with batch_write_item() too.

Here is my code snippet for few records (more than 1):

```py
import json
import boto3
import csv
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

roleARN = 'arn:aws:iam::123:role/xyz_role'

boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='test_profile')
client = boto3.client('sts')

response = client.assume_role(RoleArn=roleARN, 
                              RoleSessionName='RoleSessionName', 
                              DurationSeconds=1800)

dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='ap-south-1',
                    aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
                    aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
                    aws_session_token = response['Credentials']['SessionToken'])


#Fetching time for population
current_time = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()[:-3] + 'Z'


def convert_csv_to_json_list(file):
   items = []
   with open(file) as csvfile:
      reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
      for row in reader:
          data = {}
          data['col1'] = row['col1']
          data['col2'] = int(row['col2'])
          data['col3'] = int(row['col3'])
          data['Row_Created'] = current_time
          data['col4'] = row['col4']
          data['col5'] = int(row['col5'])
          data['Row_Updated'] = current_time
          items.append(data)
   return items


def batch_write(items):
    table = "sample_table"
    #writing batch
    try:
        print(type(items))
        dynamodb_client.batch_write_item(RequestItems = {
            table: [{'PutRequest':
            {
            'Item' : items
            }}]
            })
        print(f'resource, specify all types : write succeeded.')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'resource, specify all types : write failed: {e}')


inp_file = "sample_mapping.csv"
json_data = convert_csv_to_json_list(inp_file)
batch_write(json_data)
```

I keep getting :

```
<class 'list'>
resource, specify all types : write failed: Parameter validation failed:

Invalid type for parameter RequestItems.sample_table[0][{'col1': 'abc', 'col2': 59, 'col3': 0
, 'Row_Created': '2021-10-08T04:36:04.787Z', 'col4': 'dfrwfr', 'col5': 1, 'Row_Updated': '2021-10-08T04:36:04.787Z'}, {'col1': 'sffr', 'col2': 45, 'col3': 0
, 'Row_Created': '2021-10-08T04:36:04.787Z', 'col4': 'gty7u', 'col5': 1, 'Row_Updated': '2021-10-08T04:36:04.787Z'}], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class
'dict'>
```

Can someone help me where I am going wrong with batch insertion, tried looking up the documentation too.

Answer (score 1):

Each item should be in a separate `PutRequest` key.

```py
RequestItems = {
    table: [
        {'PutRequest': {'Item': {}}},
        {'PutRequest': {'Item': {}}}
    ]
}
```

There are [certain limitations](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.batch_write_item) with using `batch_write_item`, such as there cannot be more than 25 items in the request.

Answer (score 0):

For the error

> Invalid type for parameter ... valid types: <class
> 'dict'>

This is caused by the batch_write_item in boto3.client.

To explain, there is boto3.client and boto3.resource - Look at this ask here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373419/boto-3-dynamodb-batchwriteitem-invalid-attribute-value-type-when-specifying-type)

When using boto3.client, you need to explicitly specify the type for all your fields.

Currently, your json_data looks something like this

```
[{'col1':x, 'col2':y, ...},{'col1':x, 'col2':y, ...},{'col1':x, 'col2':y, ...},...]
```

since batch_write_items expects input to include type, your request should look something like this

```
RequestItems = {
table: [
    {'PutRequest': 
        {'Item': {
             'col1':{'S':items['col1']},
             'col2':{'N':items['col2']}
            }
        }
    }
    },
    {'PutRequest': 
        {'Item': {
             'col1':{'S':items['col1']},
             'col2':{'N':items['col2']}
            }
        }
    }


]}
```

Meaning your json_data at the end should look something like this

```
[{'col1':{'S',x}, 'col2':{'N',y}, {'col1':{'S',x}, 'col2':{'N',y}, {'col1':{'S',x}, 'col2':{'N',y} ...}
```

For the list of data type descriptors - [check out the doc here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypeDescriptors)

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb/client/batch_write_item.html#codecell2